# Retrieve an xpath text contains using text()

Tags: xpath

I've been hacking away at this one for hours and I just can't figure it out. Using XPath to find text values is tricky and this problem has too many moving parts.

I have a webpage with a large table and a section in this table contains a list of users (assignees) that are assigned to a particular unit. There is nearly always multiple users assigned to a unit and I need to make sure a particular user is assigned to any of the units on the table. I've used XPath for nearly all of my selectors and I'm half way there on this one. I just can't seem to figure out how to use `contains` with `text()` in this context.

Here's what I have so far:

```
//td[@id='unit']/span [text()='asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf (Primary); asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf, asdfasdfasdfasdf; 456, 3456'; testuser]
```

The XPath Query above captures all text in the particular section I am looking at, which is great. However, I only need to know if testuser is in that section.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`text()` gets you a set of text nodes. I tend to use it more in a context of //span//text() or something.

If you are trying to check if the text inside an element contains something you should use `contains` on the element rather than the result of `text()` like this:

```
span[contains(., 'testuser')]
```

XPath is pretty good with context. If you know exactly what text a node should have you can do:

```
span[.='full text in this span']
```

But if you want to do something like regular expressions (using exslt for example) you'll need to use the string() function:

```
span[regexp:test(string(.), 'testuser')]
```

Comment: What does the dot mean in `contains(., 'testuser')`?

Comment: the dot in span[contains(., 'testuser')] is a span node ... inside a predicate (the square brackets), you can write xpath expressions relative to the node on which the predicate is being evalueated. so span[contains(., 'testuser')] evaluates the [] predicate on span nodes and checks itself for containing text 'testuser' ... alterantely, span[contains(./span, 'testuser')] tests will check spans inside spans, matching the outer span if the inner span contains 'testuser' ... its like directory paths.

Comment: what about `matches(...)` function for regular expressions?

Comment: why can't we use the expression `//span[contains(text(), 'testuser')]` to find span elements containing the word `testuser`?