# Xpath solution for the duplicate field names in the same page

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

There are three Save buttons in the webpage which has dynamic ID. Guide me how to define the best xpath, currently I have applied the full xpath starting html node.

First Save Button HTML code

```
<button id="j_idt131" name="j_idt131" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only button" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'j_idt131',update:'csqa_form',oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) qaChangeDialog.show();}});return false;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Save</span></button>
```

Second Save Button HTML code

```
<button id="j_idt104" name="j_idt104" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only button" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'j_idt104',update:'cemail_form',oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) emailChangeDialog.show();}});return false;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Save</span></button>
```

Third Save Button HTML code

```
<button id="j_idt82" name="j_idt82" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only button" onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({source:'j_idt82',update:'cpwd_form',oncomplete:function(xhr,status,args){if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) pwdChangeDialog.show();}});return false;" type="submit" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Save</span></button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the order of the buttons, you could try this xpath,

```
//button[contains(@id,"j_idt")][1]
//button[contains(@id,"j_idt")][2] 
//button[contains(@id,"j_idt")][3]
```

Comment: But according to W3C it starts with [1]. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Vignesh you are correct. XPath is one of the funny languages that have 1-based arrays rather than 0-based arrays (which is common in a lot of other languages)

Comment: @Vignesh when i applied the same concept for anchor tags it does not work. //a[contains(text(), 'Pending New Business')][1]

Comment: @Thirumalai try //a[contains(., 'Pending New Business')][1]

Comment: @Thirumalai also look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570857/retrieve-an-xpath-text-contains-using-text explained better

Comment: @vignesh the logic works partially, most of the times it gets failed to recognize.

Comment: @Thirumalai what do you mean 'partially'. I think i answered your question, but i dont know why you unaccepted the answer after a day

Comment: @Vignesh the script is not clicking the button. so I am expecting different answer to resolve it.

Comment: @Thirumalai Are you able to find the element using the xpath?

Comment: @Vignesh No, failed to recognise the webelement

Comment: @Thirumalai Check whether it is in different frame. Can you show me the code, what you've tried

Comment: @Vignesh I used relative path to resolve this issue for the time being. 1 Save) //*[@id="csqa_form"]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/button/span 2 Save)    //*[@id="cemail_form"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/button/span  3 Save) //*[@id="cpwd_form"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/button/span

Answer (score 0):

HI can you please provide the full page markup maybe through a pastie link
I reckon you can use AxisName by selection //label[.='Answert3']/following::button[.='Save']