# Python/Selenium: Whitespace issue when retrieving text content from XPath (normalize-space)

Tags: python, xml, selenium, xpath

I am having some difficulties with a relative `XPath` web scraper implementation with `Selenium` for `Python`.

From this [Börse Frankfurt web page](http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/etp/db-x-trackers-STOXX-GLOBAL-SELECT-DIVIDEND-100-UCITS-ETF-1D-LU0292096186), I want to get the text in the cell adjacent to `<td> UCITS IV-Konform </td>`, namely the text in the cell that says `<td class="text-right"> Ja </td>`.

I have tested the XPath I'm using with [Freeformatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output) which states that my XPath is correct.

Navigation to the page works fine. However, when I try to retrieve the text content, I get `None`. Apparently, it's not finding the XPath.

**Post-answer edit**: The issue is due to *whitespace* leading/trailing the text content.

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/etp/db-x-trackers-STOXX-GLOBAL-SELECT-DIVIDEND-100-UCITS-ETF-1D-LU0292096186")

try:
    find_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()=' UCITS IV-Konform ']/following-sibling::td").text
except NoSuchElementException:
    find_value = None

print find_value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the XPath `"//td[normalize-space(.) = 'UCITS IV-Konform']/following-sibling::td"` as I think there is a lot of leading and trailing white space in that cell.

Comment: Thanks Martin, that worked! I suspected it had something to do with the whitespace. It had me dumbfounded for quite a while. Good to know about `normalize-space`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `contains` function in your xpath:

```
"//td[contains(text(), 'UCITS IV-Konform')]/following-sibling::td"
```

There is a good explanation of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570857/retrieve-an-xpath-text-contains-using-text).

Comment: Thanks for this! Good resource.